# Angular show fetched data after click dropdown button

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I use angular at the frontend and .net core at the backend. I have a trivial problem and figure it with a video below. I spend hours and hours and still couldn't solve the problem.

I simply fetch data from my web api. And use *ngFor for display the data. But the problem is data is not shown before click any dropdown button.
Btw, dropdown button does not have any click event. It's simple language selector.
When I click language selector dropdown button, it expands and at the same time my data display on the screen.

I get my data ngOnInit. I check the data on debug mode and it's ok. I really spend hours and hours...still couldn't find any solution.

My html code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let d of devices"> --> I put here breakpoint and it run when I click dropdown btn
      <span>{{d.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My .ts code:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Pagination } from '../../../_helpers/Pagination';
import { deviceListModel, NewDeviceModel } from '../../admin-panel.model';
import { AdminPanelService } from '../../admin-panel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  devices : Array<deviceListModel>; ---> I also try with public deviceList : deviceListModel[]; nothing change

  constructor(private service : PanelService, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
   this.getDeviceList();
  }

  getDeviceList() {
    this.service.getDeviceList().subscribe(res => {
      this.devices = res;
    })
  } ---> This part works fine. Data comes true from the backend before click the dropdown button.(I checked in debug mode with breakpoints)

}
```

Visiulize my problem with below link;
https://media.giphy.com/media/jYGHN1Ndxyeqhtn0ZR/giphy.gif

fullscreen with low res : https://giphy.com/gifs/jYGHN1Ndxyeqhtn0ZR/fullscreen

**Edit :**
When I try just display one of the data like devices[0].name;

```
<div>
  <span> {{devices[0}.name}} </span>
</div>
```

I get data on page but with an error in console.

The error comes three times and the error is ;
core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Hi @devtnc, Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997739/11398810

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with `detectChanges();`

add this line to the constructor:

```
private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef,
```

Then, write this line after filling your array:

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `this.devices = res;` into the NgZone

```
constructor(..., private _ngZone: NgZone)

this._ngZone.run(() => { this.devices = res; });
```

Comment: Nope, still same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put an `*ngIf` in the container? Like so:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="devices?.length">
  <div *ngFor="let d of devices">
    <span>{{d.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the template will only be rendered when the backend call has completed  successfully (and has results).